# C++ - Recommended way to allow access objects in a class to access the class they are in

Tags: c++, organization

I have a class `Game` with class `EnemyManager`. `EnemyManager` deals with spawning of enemies and the logic behind it. The problem is that `EnemyManager` needs access to functions and other `Game` objects in the game class. I can think of two ways to handle this.

1. Pass the address of the class object `Game*` using `this` as one of the arguments in the `EnemyManager`.
2. Declare a global pointer to a Game object and set it when initializing the `Game` class. Then extern it into the `enemymanager.cpp`.

Which is the more advisable way to do this?

Comment: In general, one of the concepts of OOP is that inner classes **don't** see outer classes.

Comment: My opinion - if you have just one game, you can use some global var, but better to give it some scope. Put it into a namespace.

Comment: @elyashiv So would you recommend passing individual objects pointers in arguments, i.e. EnemyManager needs to add a bullet so I pass a pointer to bullet manager to EnemyManager. Or something else?

Comment: `typeid` might be relevant (with C++11)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Why? How does `typeid` help with this?

Comment: @user3106200: In general, there's no problem with `EnemyManager` operating on a reference to `Game`, as HonkyTonk suggests (note that passing a pointer makes `nullptr` a viable argument, which it shouldn't be, because `Game` *must* exist if `EnemyManager` exists).  However, "access to functions and other Game objects in the game class" seems to suggest that `Game` has a lot of responsibilities. Beware of *god objects* which do much more than they should. The second approach isn't really a solution. You just avoid putting `Game` in `EnemyManager`s interface and open the door for global abuse.

Answer (score 5):

Whenever I encounter situations like this I review the overall design of the related classes.  If EnemyManager is a member of a Game object and needs to call things within Game, maybe those functions in Game can be factored out into a separate component.  If something you are writing is beginning to feel overly-complex or like a hack it's usually time to do some factoring.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say without knowing the overall architecture layout, but my 2 cents:

The way you describe as a first one is called the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and is widely used all around. You should keep an eye on what methods/fields you're making public. 
I assume that `Game` class has the methods that should not be accessible from the `EnemyManager` class, thus is seems like it's a good idea to create the interface which has the declaration of the methods that are used by `EnemyManager` and then pass the pointer to the `EnemyManager` instance (instead of the `Game`).

For example: The `Game` class implements `IGameEnemyManager`, and you're passing `IGameEnemyManager` using this as one of the initialization arguments.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with object oriented designs, it is typically good to think about who will act how on what to find a first version of a design. After having written this version, one often finds the weaknesses and rewrite it for the second iteration.

So, in this case, the `Game` class manages the world (I assume) and offers different ways to manipulate it. Your `EnemyManager` manages one aspect of the world, enemies, but they do live inside the world.

```
class Enemy {
public:
  Enemy(Location& location, int hitpoints);
  bool Move(Direction& direction);
};

class Game {
public:
  bool CreateInitialState();
  bool AddEnemy(Enemy& enemy);
  bool AddBullet(Location& location, Direction& direction, int speed);
  void Render();
};

class EnemyManager {
public:
  EnemyManager(Game& game);
  void MoveEnemies();
};
```

In this first version, all types see each other as proper classes and manipulates things by calling the appropriate method. This offers little support for expanding on the game if you want to add new things to it.

This is where interfaces become handy and you can try to think about how the different parts will interact instead of how they should be implemented.

```
class Canvas {
public:
  // Different graphical primitives.
};

class GameObject {
public:
  virtual ~GameObject() {};
  virtual void Draw(Canvas& canvas) = 0;
  virtual bool Move(Direction& direction) = 0;
};

class GlobalState {
public:
  virtual AddGameObject(GameObject& gameObject) = 0;
};

class Game : public Canvas, public GlobalState {
public:
  bool CreateInitialState();

  void Render() {
    // Send itself to the Draw method in all GameObjects that have been added
  }

  // Other game logic
};

class Enemy : public GameObject {
  // This can be specialized even more if you need to
};

class Bullet : public GameObject {
  // This can also be specialized even more if you need to
};
```

This separates design from implementation and, as I see it, is a good way to end up with a proper first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling `game objects` in `EnemyManager`, why is it part of the class `Game` ? I suppose you should consider reviewing your design as there are chances of circular reference problem if you don't handle the scenarios well.

`Consider segregating both the classes to ensure a single responsibility principle.

 Define proper interface in your`EnemyManager`to Game object as argument and act on the functions`

These are little suggestions that I can think of with limited idea about your design

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely need to use the 1st approach, but with a few changes: you should disintegrate your `Game` class to more components. For example you can create a `SceneManager` class, which is responsible for all game object's creation/management. When you're instantiating the `EnemyManager` - just pass a pointer to it:

```
// in SceneManager
EnemyManager* emgr = new EnemyManager(this);
InterfaceManager* imgr = new InterfaceManager(this);
```

Note that your `SceneManager` class should provide a complete  interface

```
// in EnemyManager
GameObject* spawnEnemyAt(string name, EnemyClass* eclass, Vector3 position, AIBehaviour* behaviour)
{
    GameObject* myEnemy = smgr->createGameObject(name, position, etc...);
    //register an enemy in the enemies list, initialize it's behaviour and do any other logic

    return myEnemy
}
```

This approach should help you not to ruin your architecture and not to be captured in the `friend`(class)-zone.

---

**[Upd.]** Note that my approach assumes that all objects on the scene are `GameObject`s, there's neither `Enemy` nor `Player` classes. Every `GameObject` *may* has a `Renderer`, `Animator`, `AIBehaviour` components.